# Can fstab dynamically mount a partition by reading from a file or filename?

Tags: linux, debian, mount, partition, fstab

I have a partition structure as follows:

```
/dev/sdc1 => Partition 1 ( My OS. [ Linux flavour ] )
/dev/sdc2 => Partition 2 ( This contents some data. )
/dev/sdc3 => Partition 3 ( This also contents some data. )
/dev/sdc4 => Partition 4 ( I want this as a deciding partition. )
```

I am trying to mount partition 2 or partition 3 dynamically depending on the file present in partition 4.

**For example:-** Partition 2 will be mounted if partition 4 consists of a file named `two`. Partition 3 will be mounted if partition 4 consists of a file named `three`.

**Note:-** This partition will never be mounted together i.e. if Partition 2 is mounted partition 3 will be not be mounted until partition 2 is unmounted. Thus I can use a common directory for both partitions.

As I have systemd available on my os I can write a startup script which can read from partition 4 and mount the appropriate partition at boot and write the partition record into /etc/fstab.

But according to my understanding fstab is critical file and if any failure happens or fstab get's corrupt it's going to stop the system from booting.

**Question:**

Now what I am trying to achieve is can I add an entry in fstab which will read dynamically partition 4 and add the entry for partition 2 or partition 3 depending on the file that exists in the partition 4.

Comment: I don't think you can do that, I would do it with a script

Comment: Yes after searching for some time I also came up with the same conclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution should be systemd-based, you do NOT have to edit `/etc/fstab` with systemd, why would you ? You just mount the partition, depending on the factors you have outlined, and leave it at that.

I do not understand why you would want to edit `/etc/fstab` if systemd can mount what you need. Do note that systemd will refuse to boot if an entry in `/etc/fstab` is not available. This entails that on systems with systemd, `/etc/fstab` should only be used for boot-essential static file systems.

Answer (score 1):

> But according to my understanding fstab is critical file and if any failure happens or fstab get's corrupt it's going to stop the system from booting.

Right.

> Now what I am trying to achieve is can I add an entry in fstab which will read dynamically partition 4 and add the entry for partition 2 or partition 3 depending on the file that exists in the partition 4.

With the proper commands and access rights, you can actually write into any file, including `/etc/fstab`.

What will happen if you try to do so is that anything you write into `fstab` will be written there WAY AFTER the OS has read it and mounted the appropriate filesystems.

- At best, your changes have no effect.
- At worst, any error or typo you made in your `/etc/fstab` edits will actually "pop out" on the next reboot (which will be REALLY bad news on a shared machine, or on a machine with decent uptime as you possibly won't remember tampering with `/etc/fstab`)